# SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'activity_log' already exists

Tags: laravel-5

In Connection.php line 664:

> SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table
>   'activity_log' already exists (SQL: create table `activity_log` (`id`
>   int      unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `log_name`
>   varchar(255) null, `description` text not null, `subject_id` int null,
>   `subject_     type` varchar(255) null, `causer_id` int null,
>   `causer_type` varchar(255) null, `properties` text null, `created_at`
>   timestamp null, `upd     ated_at` timestamp null) default character
>   set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci)

In PDOStatement.php line 123:

```
  SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'activity_log' already exists
```

In PDOStatement.php line 121:

```
 SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'activity_log' already exists
```

Comment: you are obviously trying to create a table that already exists, you will either need to check if it exists and skip the creation or drop the table first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahmed Gamal the table is already in your database, so you need to drop that table. Have you try **php artisan migrate:fresh**.